# How to return the result of a subtest in python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am using python unittest subtests. I need to pass the result of the subtest to a database.
I am aware that there is the option of using: `self.defaultTestResult()` and `unittest.TestResult()`.
The problem is that this provides the result of the base test, not the subtest. Is there a way to get the result of the subtest instead without waiting for the base test to end and picking apart the output string?

```
import unittest
class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_even(self):
        """
        Test that numbers between 0 and 5 are all even.
        """
        for i in range(0, 6):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertEqual(i % 2, 0)

unittest.main()
```

Comment: Consider to use parametrised tests rather than `self.subTest`.

Comment: So is there no way to get the current result of the subtest?

Comment: I see the appeal of paramaterize. Thank you, is there a way to get the current result of those tests?

Comment: That worked out so well. No work around or anything. like magic.